# Complex Google Sheets Puzzle - Help appreciated - Link to sheet included

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [finance sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FfzPVaec0NGlUlpr9ywClGcPtqHnr3nCOBWD799SSrM/edit#gid=0) that tracks the following in different columns:

- (A) Amount Already Built Into Budget for the Year [Purple]
- (B) Amount Spent Year-to-Date [Red]
- (C,E,G,I) Q1-Q4 Reimbursement amounts [Green]
- (D,F,H,J) Q1-Q4 Hidden columns to be used to help create this function and to tick on and off based on reimbursement amount input [Gold]
- (K) **Reimbursement Remaining** [Blue]

The amount already built into the budget needs to be divided by 4 and to show up on each quarter as reimbursed. That amount will be entered into each quarter by default with a code that divides Column A by 4. The user will replace that value each quarter by adding the column K value to the value for that quarter.

Each quarter, the user should be able to add the value in column K to the appropriate quarter and end up with zero balance in column K.

The Amount Spent Column will update monthly and include:

- Expenses built into the budget to-date
- Additional expenses to-date

The goal of this sheet is to allow someone to input how much was actually reimbursed in the Q1-Q4 Reimbursement amounts [Green] and to provide a tool for that person to know how much needs to be reimbursed at any given time in the **Reimbursement Remaining** [Blue] column.

Column K needs to still be able to function if all expenses appear in the actuals Q4--meaning, Column K will need to be zero for Q1-Q3 and only show a balance if the sum of the actuals recorded  exceeds what was built into the budget.

Wow that was hard to write out.

What is a formula that could go in Column K to make this work?

I hope this makes sense to someone!

-Alfred

Comment: this is unclear ... `Each quarter, the user should be able to add the value in column K to the appropriate quarter` ... does the user do this manually? ... more hidden columns are probably required for correct functionality

Comment: Thanks for checking! Yes, the user was supposed to update Columns C,E,G,I manually according to what the running reimbursement amount said. Inputting that amount should have brought Column K to a zero balance. That balance would then increase as the Amount Spent column increased throughout the year.

Comment: the difficulty may be caused by preloading Q1-Q4 data ... also the desired functionality of column K may be flawed ... my thinking is that maybe column K should display 1/4 of yearly budget only when no quarter data is entered .... when one of the quarter data is entered then column K should display 1/3 of the remaining yearly budget, and so on

Comment: Thanks for this insight! I think you're on to something. I'm going to work on it and see if I can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=if(C2+E2+G2+I2=A2+B2,0,
if(AND(D2+F2+H2+J2=0,D2=0),B2-C2,
if(AND(D2+F2+H2+J2=1,D2=1),B2-C2,
if(AND(D2+F2+H2+J2=1,F2=1),B2-C2-E2,
if(AND(D2+F2+H2+J2=1,H2=1),B2-C2-E2-G2,
if(AND(D2+F2+H2+J2=1,J2=1),B2-C2-E2-G2-I2, 0)
)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! That almost works as intended, but it doesn't function correctly if I start by entering values in Q2-Q4. I need it to work so that it can skip Quarters if no additional expenses are reported for a previous Quarter.